# Taking turns picking endpoints, trying to get max

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Say there is an array of integers.  You take turns with another person picking endpoints of the array (either first or last element).  Objective is to implement an algorithm to find the maximum score possible (always being the first to act).

example:

```
int[] arr = {3, 0, 4, 11, 1};

pick 3
arr = {0, 4, 11, 1}

opponent picks 0 
arr = {4, 11, 1}

pick 4
arr = {11, 1}

opponent picks 1
arr = {11}

pick 11
arr = {}

maxPossible = 3 + 4 + 11 = 18
```

I got a recursive solution working, but it is very inefficient.

I want to find the dynamic programming solution (I am new to it).

Any ideas?

Here is my naive recursive implementation.  I believe it's O(2^N)

```
public int findBest(List<Integer> a) {
       return findBestHelper(a, 0, true);
}

public int findBestHelper(List<Integer> a, int score, boolean myTurn) {

    if(a.size() <= 0)
        return score;

    List<Integer> removeFirst = new ArrayList<Integer>(a);
    removeFirst.remove(0);

    List<Integer> removeLast = new ArrayList<Integer>(a);
    removeLast.remove(removeLast.size() - 1);

    if(myTurn)
        return Math.max(findBestHelper(removeFirst, score + a.get(0), false), findBestHelper(removeLast, score + a.get(a.size() - 1), false));
    else
        return Math.max(findBestHelper(removeFirst, score, true), findBestHelper(removeLast, score, true));

}
```

Comment: And what's your attempted solution?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup added my naive recursive implementation

Comment: Shouldn't that be  {4, 11, 1} after "opponent picks 0"? At least, he might choose the 0 because then he forces you to pick 4 or 1, and knows that he can get the 11. BTW: It's not clear whether there should be an assumption about whether the opponent is "intelligent" or not, but that probably does not matter here.

Comment: @Marco13 Yes you are right about the first part.  And the algorithm is just trying to find the highest possible score that you can get, over all combinations of moves.

Comment: Are you sure there is a solution with dynamic programming? I doubt that you can do it without testing all combinations

Comment: @taytay Yes, I believe so.  I came across this question from a reputable source that suggested dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

A trial with your example.

```
public void test()
    {
        int[] arr = {3, 0, 4, 11, 1};
        int sum = 0;
        int c1, c2, rs;
        for(int i=0;i< arr.length/2; i++)
        {
         c1 =  arr[i]  ;
         c2 = arr[arr.length - i -1];
         System.out.println("c1="+c1 + " - c2="+c2);
           sum += (c1>c2) ?c1:c2;

        }
        if(arr.length%2 >0)
        {
         System.out.println("center="+arr[arr.length/2]);
            sum += arr[arr.length/2];
        }
        System.out.println("sum="+sum );
    }
```

Comment: Does not work for int[] arr = {3, 0, 4, 11, 1, 1}, which should give 18, but your solution gives 15.  The problem is your `c1 =` and `c2 =` are only checking the opposite endpoints.  But you also need to check the index after what you pick/remove, because the opponent can also pick.  I do not think your solution has the right approach, but  not sure.  I do not see where the dynamic programming aspect is

Comment: The question was just to find the maximum points that can be produced by following the pick pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is optimum, but I really wanted to give it a try :D

```
/**
 * @param array
 * @return
 */
public static int getMax(int[] array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int lastIndex = array.length - 1;
    boolean firstLarger = array[0] > array[lastIndex];
    return (firstLarger ? array[0] : array[lastIndex]) 
        + getMax(removeMin(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, firstLarger ? 1 : 0, firstLarger ? lastIndex + 1
        : lastIndex)));
}

/**
 * @param array
 * @return
 */
public static int[] removeMin(int[] array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return array;
    }
    int lastIndex = array.length - 1;
    boolean firstLarger = array[0] > array[lastIndex];
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, firstLarger ? 0 : 1, firstLarger ? lastIndex : lastIndex + 1);
}
```

Comment: Well it is faster than my naive solution, but not sure if it is optimal (O(N), if its possible).  And are you sure this features dynamic programming?

Comment: This is a greedy approach. On each iteration it picks min/max depending on your turn. It works on O(N) but I don't know if it finds global maximum or stucks at a local maximum

Comment: Looks like it is not. For example "2 1 1 4 3" Greedy approach first picks 3 1 4 and finds 8 while best solution is 2 3 4 = 9

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming suggests we need some subset of the problem with
trivial solutions and a way to extend a subset solution with more data.

I'm not entirely sure how this done here but here is a guess regarding
which direction you need to go in.

The trivial case is where we only have one array element left. Score
of the optimal solution is the value of that element.

If we have all solutions for arrays with length n we can get the optimal
solution for a n + 1  length array by comparing (beginning of the array - optimal solution 
of the n length array without the start element) with (ending of array - optimal solution 
of the n length array without the end element)

So something like:

```
elems   2            3           4           5
3       B(3-0)3      E(4-3)1     E(11-1)10   B(3-6)-3
0       E(4-0)4      E(11-4)7    B(0- -6)6
4       E(11-4)7     B(4-10)-6
11      B(11-1)10
1
```

First column is when there is only one element. Second column is the 2 length array etc.
each row is the array starting from that index. So we get the cell in the first row and second column by comparing (3 - optimal solution of first column second row) with (0 -
optimal solution of fist column first row).

Most likely I've made a mistake or two in writing down the decisions and score, but
I think the general idea might have some merit.

-edit-

Ahmad Y. Saleh solution looks greedy to me. I don't think this gives you the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the recursive solution is that it computes many sequences of states multiple times. Imagine starting with the list

```
[10, 48, 29, 47, 15, 3, 41, 11, 19, 4]
```

Now imagine two possible sequences of moves. The following lines contain

1. The list of the current state
2. The scores of both players
3. The index of the active playere (0 or 1)

The start of the first sequence:

```
List [10, 48, 29, 47, 15, 3, 41, 11, 19, 4], scores [0, 0], active 0
List [10, 48, 29, 47, 15, 3, 41, 11, 19], scores [4, 0], active 1
List [10, 48, 29, 47, 15, 3, 41, 11], scores [4, 19], active 0
List [48, 29, 47, 15, 3, 41, 11], scores [14, 19], active 1
List [29, 47, 15, 3, 41, 11], scores [14, 67], active 0
...
```

The start of the second sequence:

```
List [10, 48, 29, 47, 15, 3, 41, 11, 19, 4], scores [0, 0], active 0
List [48, 29, 47, 15, 3, 41, 11, 19, 4], scores [10, 0], active 1
List [29, 47, 15, 3, 41, 11, 19, 4], scores [10, 48], active 0
List [29, 47, 15, 3, 41, 11, 19], scores [14, 48], active 1
List [29, 47, 15, 3, 41, 11], scores [14, 67], active 0
...
```

At this point, both sequences arrived at the same state! Basically, a simple and intuitive summary is that the sequence

```
Player 0 takes right
Player 1 takes right
Player 0 takes left 
Player 1 takes left
```

and

```
Player 0 takes left
Player 1 takes left
Player 0 takes right
Player 1 takes right
```

result in the same state. In the recursive solution, the computation continues with the resulting state *twice*, and duplicate states that occur later are again handled *twice* - and this "tree" grows rather fast.

So one way of tackling this with some sort of dynamic programming is the following: Starting from a certain game state, one could compute all possible successors, and store them in a set. Then compute the successors of these states, keeping track of the score that was achieved so far.

This is an implementation of this approach, which also prints the results that have been skipped:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class PickingGame
{
    private static final boolean PRINT_SKIPPED_STATES = true;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //solve(Arrays.asList(3, 0, 4, 11, 1));
        solve(createLargerList());
    }

    private static List<Integer> createLargerList()
    {
        int max = 50;
        int n = 10;
        Random random = new Random(0);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            list.add(random.nextInt(max));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static void solve(List<Integer> list)
    {
        System.out.println("Starting with "+list);

        Set<PickingGameState> currentStates = 
            new LinkedHashSet<PickingGameState>();
        currentStates.add(new PickingGameState(list));
        Set<PickingGameState> finalStates = 
            new LinkedHashSet<PickingGameState>();
        while (!currentStates.isEmpty())
        {
            PickingGameState currentState = currentStates.iterator().next();
            currentStates.remove(currentState);
            if (currentState.list.size() == 0)
            {
                finalStates.add(currentState);
            }
            else 
            {
                PickingGameState next0 = new PickingGameState(currentState, true);
                boolean changed0 = currentStates.add(next0);
                if (PRINT_SKIPPED_STATES && !changed0)
                {
                    printDebugInfo(currentStates, next0);
                }

                if (currentState.list.size() > 1)
                {
                    PickingGameState next1 = new PickingGameState(currentState, false);
                    boolean changed1 = currentStates.add(next1);
                    if (PRINT_SKIPPED_STATES && !changed1)
                    {
                        printDebugInfo(currentStates, next0);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        int maxScore = 0;
        PickingGameState maxPickingGameState = null;
        for (PickingGameState p : finalStates)
        {
            if (p.scores[0] > maxScore)
            {
                maxScore = p.scores[0];
                maxPickingGameState = p;
            }
            if (p.scores[1] > maxScore)
            {
                maxScore = p.scores[1];
                maxPickingGameState = p;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The best result that can be achieved is");
        print(maxPickingGameState);
    }

    // Print all predecessors of the given state,
    // and finally the state itself
    private static void print(PickingGameState p)
    {
        if (p.predecessor == null)
        {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        else
        {
            print(p.predecessor);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

    // Print details about the given state that was ignored
    // because an "equal" state was already in the given
    // sequence
    private static void printDebugInfo(
        Iterable<PickingGameState> iterable, PickingGameState newState)
    {
        System.out.println("Ignoring "+newState);
        System.out.println("It was achieved with this sequence of moves:");
        print(newState);
        System.out.println("But the same state was already achieved with");
        print(findEqual(iterable, newState));
        System.out.println("");
    }

    // Returns the first element in the given sequence
    // that is equal to the given element
    private static <T> T findEqual(Iterable<T> iterable, T element)
    {
        for (T e : iterable)
        {
            if (e.equals(element))
            {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}


class PickingGameState
{
    PickingGameState predecessor;
    List<Integer> list;
    int scores[];
    int active;

    PickingGameState(List<Integer> list)
    {
        this.predecessor = null;
        this.list = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
        this.scores = new int[2]; 
        this.active = 0;
    }
    PickingGameState(PickingGameState other, boolean removeFirst)
    {
        this.predecessor = other;
        this.list = new ArrayList<Integer>(other.list);
        this.scores = other.scores.clone();
        if (removeFirst)
        {
            this.scores[other.active] += this.list.remove(0);
        }
        else
        {
            this.scores[other.active] += this.list.remove(this.list.size()-1);
        }
        this.active = 1-other.active;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "List "+list+", scores "+Arrays.toString(scores)+", active "+active;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + active;
        result = prime * result + ((list == null) ? 0 : list.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(scores);
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PickingGameState other = (PickingGameState) obj;
        if (active != other.active)
            return false;
        if (list == null)
        {
            if (other.list != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!list.equals(other.list))
            return false;
        if (!Arrays.equals(scores, other.scores))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```